# Redirect From Login Page In Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

Ok Guys i Have 2 pages one Login and One Page is the Form Registration I want that the Login Page should come first and only after Login succesfull it redirects to the Registration page. It was easy for me in the Web Approach using Session variables but when i am trying to do it in the Windows Application The Registration page is coming first and only after logout from Registration page then My whole thing is working correct. But i want that on startup itself the Login page should come.

This is the Code i wrote

```
//----THIS IS IN THE REGISTRATION PAGE
        public static string Admin="";
protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnVisibleChanged(e);
        this.Visible = false;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //--------------------------WORKS WHEN FORM IS LOADED
        //this.Visible=false;
        if (Admin == "")
        {
            this.Hide();
            LoginObject.Show();
            //this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Admin = LoginObject.AdminId();
            this.Show();
            FormLoaded();
        }
//--------------THIS IS IN LOGIN PAGE

public static string Admin="";
private void ButtonLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string AdminUserName = TextUserName.Text;
        string AdminPassword = TextPassword.Text;

        //--------------------------------VERIFY ADMIN 

        GetSetAdmin.AdminUserName = AdminUserName;
        GetSetAdmin.AdminPassword = AdminPassword;
        BusinessClassAdminLogin BusniessObject = new BusinessClassAdminLogin();
        string AdminAuthorised = BusniessObject.ValidateAdmin(GetSetAdmin);
        if (!AdminAuthorised.Contains("-1"))
        {
            //Session["Admin"] = AdminAuthorised;
            //Response.Redirect("EmpRegistration.aspx");
            Admin = AdminAuthorised;
            EmpRegistration EmpRegObject = new EmpRegistration();
            this.Hide();
            EmpRegObject.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("UserName or Passowrd Dont Match");
        }
    }
//---------------------MAIN FUNCTIOn 
   static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        //Application.Run(new EmpRegistration());
        Application.Run(new Login());
    }
```

Comment: where is your static main function ??

Comment: static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            //Application.Run(new EmpRegistration());
            Application.Run(new Login());
        }

Comment: Your code looks fine for me.After `Login` what you want to do??

Comment: The thing is along with Login Page Emp Registration page is also coming

Comment: what is `FormLoaded()`?

Comment: Please post code for Login_Load()

Comment: FormLoaded() is the function for clearing values on Page Load itself and i need some EmpId values from databse so that is it

Comment: @Amit i did not create or wrote anything on its load as i did not needed it.

Answer (score 0):

In main page instead of default set Login page as start page. You can use the base form or singleton class for storing the login information.